# Apache Pyspark : How to run the batch analytics on thousands of devices every day

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, analytics

I'm new to Spark, and I want to run daily analytics on a large number of iot devices. I am reading data from HDFS , processing using spark and writing to MongoDB. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this. Should I submit one Spark job with a for loop to iterate over a list of devices, or should I create one Spark job for each device? Here's the code I'm currently considering:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("BatteryDataAnalysis") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define the data source path (adjust as needed)
data_source_path = "hdfs://your-hdfs-path/data/battery_data"

# List all battery files in the data source directory
devices_files = [os.path.join(data_source_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(data_source_path) if filename.endswith(".csv")]

# Iterate through each device file and process them separately
for device_file in devices_files:
    # Load data for the current device into a Spark DataFrame
    df = spark.read.csv(device_file, header=True, inferSchema=True)

    # Preprocess and transform the data as needed for this device
    # You can perform device-specific operations here

    # Perform your analysis for this device (replace this with your actual analysis code)
    # For example, calculate statistics or perform machine learning tasks

    # Save the results for this device to an output location (adjust as needed)
    # You can save the results to a file, database, or any other desired destination
    # Write the insights to MongoDB

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

Comment: Do you mean to analyze data OF large no. of devices or to run spark ON large no. of IoT devices? The first is the bread and butter of spark. The second is madness. The best would be to collect data from IoT devices at a central location through APIs, process it on AWS cluster and then send the results to them. If you need real-time processing, you can choose Spark Structured Streaming as an option.

Comment: You will find many articles on this topic. Here are 4 different links. Search about Apache Kakfa : https://www.infoq.com/articles/traffic-data-monitoring-iot-kafka-and-spark-streaming/

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6781/real-time-iot-analytics-apache-sparks-structured-streaming-databricks-delta-lake/

https://expeed.com/get-real-time-iot-data-analytics-using-apache-kafka-and-apache-spark/

https://www.informatica.com/blogs/real-time-iot-data-ingestion-and-predictive-analytics-using-spark-structured-streaming-databricks-and-informatica.html

Comment: We are not doing real tiem analytics. Its batch analytics. Also we are not using any cloud. We have our own servers. Everyday after preprocessing we store the data in HDFS. End of day we need run analytics and generate insights for each and every IoT device. So we are using spark for computing and generating different insights. I have 1 lakh devices now to run analytics on each and every device should i submit the same apache job 1 lkah times or in the apache job i need to for loop all the devices and leave it for spark to parallel run the devices and generate insights.

Comment: We fetch one full days data from HDFS and do analytics on that using spark.